# TypeLoadException from Logger.Create when running DotNetOpenAuth under mono

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm following a simple [tutorial on DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/programmatic-openid-relying-party/). It works fine when i run it in my localhost visual studio development machine.

However, as soon as a I move it to a testing/staging server that is running mono it throws the following error:

> Location: Page_Load

```
 An exception was thrown by the type initializer for DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting
InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for DotNetOpenAuth.Logger ---> System.TypeLoadException: A type                             load exception has occurred.
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Logger.Create (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Logger.CreateWithBanner (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Logger..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting.set_Enabled (Boolean value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
StackTrace:   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty..ctor (ICryptoKeyStore cryptoKeyStore, INonceStore nonceStore) [0x00000] in <filename unknow                            n>:0
  at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty..ctor (IOpenIdApplicationStore applicationStore) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MyApp.Login_Google.Page_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

My Page load code looks like this:

```c#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
    var response = openid.GetResponse();
    if (response != null)
    {
        switch (response.Status)
        {
            case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:

                // This is where you would look for any OpenID extension responses included
                // in the authentication assertion.
                var claimsResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();

                //Database.ProfileFields = claimsResponse;

                //// Store off the "friendly" username to display -- NOT for username lookup
                //Database.FriendlyLoginName = response.FriendlyIdentifierForDisplay;

                // Use FormsAuthentication to tell ASP.NET that the user is now logged in,
                // with the OpenID Claimed Identifier as their username.
                //FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);


                break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Canceled:
                //this.loginCanceledLabel.Visible = true;
                break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.Failed:
                //this.loginFailedLabel.Visible = true;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

This is the line which causes the error:

```c#
OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
```

Mono Version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.5 (Debian 2.10.5-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  x86
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Comment: What version of DotNetOpenAuth are you running?

Comment: @AndrewArnott version 4.0.1.12097

Comment: unified assembly or the nuget distribution with many smaller assemblies?

Comment: @AndrewArnott unified single assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a difference in how mono loads assemblies, throwing different exceptions than Microsoft's CLR does.  I've filed [issue #151](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/issues/151) to track this.

In the meantime, please try downloading [this patched build](http://sdrv.ms/KYDLkh), which is v4.0.3 with the proposed fix for this bug, and see if it works for you.

This assumes that otherwise, the normal builds work on mono.

Comment: (+1) I tried the patch build but I get the same result. I noticed you closed the issue#151, is there anything I can do to help fix this? Even if it means giving you  access to my environment. Otherwise I have to choose another API or worse, purchase a Microsoft License.

Comment: I installed MonoDevelop IDE hoping I would be able to debug the error. But it also works fine in the MonoDevelop IDE. It's only failing on my Ubuntu Mod_Mono. Very strange, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Same thing. But I've moved my site to a windows hosting service so I'm not so worried about it anymore. Although I would move back to mono if this is fixed.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott I am still having an issue running this under Mono 2.10.  It's different than capdragon is experiencing though. http://pastebin.com/xh51ntbi

Comment: @rhooligan yours looks very much like a straightforward mono bug.  Can you file a bug against them?

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue by simply adding the log4net DLL to the project directory and everything works.