# MonoMac + GoogleDriveSdk Assembly not found?

Tags: c#, mono, google-drive-api, monomac

I'm trying to do a simple mac app that can interact with google drive sdk, but it seems that mono can not load or find the assembly. I'm sure I've all the dlls referenced in the project and they're in the output folder.

Haven't tried with mono on windows, but i've tried the same code with .net in windows and it works. I've read something about libgdata-cil-dev [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66343/monodevelop-google-api-gdata-assembly-not-found), but I do not have any idea how to install that on a mac

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!

It's compiling. What I did?

Well first of all I tried with the [QuickStart Sample Code](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs#step_2_install_the_google_client_library) and it failed.

I downloaded the source from http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2

And copy the files in my project

- Google.Apis.Drive.v2.cs
- Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.cs (this file is not required for the Quickstart demo)

Removed the dependencies

- Google.Apis.Drive.v2
- Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 (this reference is not required for the Quickstart demo)

Add a reference to

- log4net [TypeLoadException from Logger.Create when running DotNetOpenAuth under mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805773/typeloadexception-from-logger-create-when-running-dotnetopenauth-under-mono)

And it Built!!!